# R: Line plotting in a simpler shorter way

Tags: r, plot

I'm doing some line plotting. I have this matrix:

```
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
1  0.1  0.2  0.3
2  0.5  1.0  1.5
3  1.0  1.5  2.0
4  1.5  2.0  2.5
```

And I compute the *L1 norm* of each matrix column. So the norm for each column will be `[1] 3.1 4.7 6.3` the *L1 norm* will be the x-axis. Each Matrix row will be the y-axis.

So, for **x** `[1] 3.1 4.7 6.3` and **y** `0.1  0.2  0.3` I plot one line.

For **x** `[1] 3.1 4.7 6.3` and **y** `0.5  1.0  1.5` I plot another line  line, and so on.

Here is the code, which does it:

```
mat=matrix(c(0.1,0.5, 1, 1.5, 0.2, 1, 1.5 ,2,0.3, 1.5, 2, 2.5), nrow=4, ncol=3)
rownames(mat) <- seq_len(nrow(mat))
norm1=as.vector(rep(0,3))
for (i in 1:3) {
  norm1[i]=norm(as.matrix(mat[,i]))   
}
y1=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)
y2=c(0.5,1.0,1.5)
y3=c(1.0,1.5,2)
y4=c(1.5,2,2.5)
plot(norm1,y1, type = "l", xlim=c(3,7), ylim=c(0,3)) 
lines(norm1,y2)
lines(norm1,y3)
lines(norm1,y4)
```

Is there any other way how I could do the plotting simpler and shorter? If I would have a matrix 100x20 I would have to write for each row a `y1=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)` and add to many `lines(norm1,y4)`.

And here is the plot: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
L1 <- function(x) sum(abs(x));
bind_cols(
    as.data.frame(mat) %>%
        summarise_all(funs(L1(.))) %>%
        t() %>%
        as.data.frame() %>%
        rename(x = V1),
    t(mat) %>%
        as.data.frame() %>%
        rename_all(funs(gsub("V", "", .)))) %>%
    gather(row, y, 2:5) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x, y, colour = row)) + geom_line();
```

[image]

Comment: Huh, I thought that *"plotting simpler and shorter"* meant shorter, more-concise code. This looks nicer, no doubt.

Comment: Yes agreed @r2evans; I just wanted to show an alternative. Your solution is a lot more concise.

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
# automated lims here, you can easily override
plot(NA, xlim=range(norm1), ylim=range(mat))
for (r in seq_len(nrow(mat))) lines(norm1, mat[r,])
```